# Show that G is not a simple group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^kb$ where $p$ is a prime and $b>1$ is a positive integer and $p$ does not divides $b$, and $p^k$ does not divides $(b-1)!$. Show that $G$ cannot be a simple group.

I don't have any idea for this question, plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be set of all lef cosets of a sylow $p$ subgroup. Then $G$ acts on $\Omega$ by left multiplication.

Now assume that $G$ is simple. By action we have a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_b$. As kernel must be trivial then $|G|$ divides $b!$.

Hence, $p^k$ divides $b!$. But since $p^k$ does not divides $(b-1)!$, we have $p$ divides $b$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. However, is it should be $p^kb$ divides $b!$?

Comment: yes $p^k$ divides $b!$. But it is given that $p^k$ does not divides $(b-1)!$ hence atleast $p$ must divides $b$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Could you explain that why it is $p^k$ divides $b!$?

Comment: As kernel is trivial, $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_b$. By Lagrange theorem, $|G|$ divides $b!$.